# How to add header file path in CMake file

Tags: cmake, opencl

I am new to OpenCL. I have written a vector addition code in OpenCL with help from Internet. I have included one header file i.e. `CL/cl.h` using `#include`.

I am using NVIDIA graphic card and the OpenCL implementation is NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK. My OpenCL header files are residing at this path `/opt/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc`. I can run OpenCL programs through linux terminal by adding this path when compiling my code. But now I want to write CMake file for this code. CMake files are working fine for C programs, but not OpenCL programs because of this Path problem. In terminal, I used to enter `$cmake .`, after this `$make`, it will search for a Makefile which is created by cmake, now my error is  after entering command `make`

```
fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory!
```

Now tell me how can I include this header file into CMake file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to put these lines into CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(/opt/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc)
link_directories(/opt/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/<lib or something similar>)

add_executable(yourexe src1.c ...)
target_link_libraries(yourexe OpenCL)
```

But beware that this is not portable, because OpenCL SDK can be somewhere else on another machine. The proper way to do this is to use `FindOpenCL.cmake` module.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is very helpful,the libraries has been linked now. My prog is getting compiled, i can run make also, after running make i am getting the error like "failed to load kernel". See the code below, this is defined by me only, it means the compiler fialed to open the ".cl"(without quotes) extension file. Can you please solve this error.
    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) 
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
     }

Comment: I installed Intel OpenCL and on my Kubuntu machine I did include_directories(/usr/include/CL) and the same for link_directories. It worked, thanks!

Comment: I like this solution because I built the OpenCL.lib file myself from http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/icd/2.0/opengl-icd-2.0.5.0.tgz and downloaded the includes and FindOpenCL.cmake does not building the library yourself. Intel, Nvidia, and SDK all include far more things then I need to download and Intel now requires registration. Better to build it yourself. On top of that AMDs cl.hpp file disagrees with the one from Khronos. It took me a while to figure that out because AMD header uses min/max which required me to use NOMINMAX with MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a CMake "find" script like:

- http://gitorious.org/findopencl/findopencl/blobs/master/FindOpenCL.cmake
- http://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/cmake/FindOpenCL.cmake?r=14

CMake file example from OpenCL Programming Guide Book: http://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/CMakeLists.txt?r=14

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for FindOpenCL.cmake macro which would work well on Windows, OSX and Linux... I couldn't find any which did work well on every platform, so I wrote new one which I use in couple of projects (webcl-validator and opencl-testsuite).

https://github.com/elhigu/cmake-findopencl

Especially Windows support is improved in this one.

In Windows it checks if 64bit or 32bit lib should be used and it also tries to find libraries from according to environment variables set by Nvidia, Intel and AMD OpenCL SDKs.

It also tries to find .lib in Cygwin, which didn't work with other scripts I tried.

Comment: And ofcourse I just found out that cmake has accepted FindOpenCL.cmake to their official branch. So in next stable release hopefully it is included.

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob_plain;f=Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake;hb=HEAD