# CMake cant find OpenCL_LIBRARY in Windows 10 and NVidia SDK

Tags: c, windows, opencl, nvidia

CMake 3.7.1 is returning the following error message

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenCL (missing: OpenCL_LIBRARY OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I download the NVidia CUDA SKD, I think it was supose to work just fine with OpenCL.

My system is Windows 10 with Visual Studio 14 2015.

FIXED:

I needed to restart my PC after installing NVidia SDK.

Comment: Does [this] solve Your problem? (tl;dr NVidia CUDA SDK does not provide FindOpenCl.cmake, so You need to get one.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346403/cmake-can-not-find-opencl-sdk-by-nvida

Comment: Turns out I need only to restart my PC.

Comment: Crap. That's the case with installs on Windows then... :D

Answer (score 0):

I needed to restart my PC after installing NVidia SDK. – Thadeu Antonio Ferreira Melo